# TypeError: Failed to execute 'item' on 'HTMLCollection': 1 argument required, but only 0

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, telerik

I'm doing cross browser javascript and the line of javascript below works fine in IE11 but doesn't work in Chrome.

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input').item().checked;
```

The error message I get is: TypeError: Failed to execute 'item' on 'HTMLCollection': 1 argument required, but only 0

Comment: `.item` returns a single element based on index passed as an arg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item

Comment: As `getElementsByTagName` return a node list, do e.g. this `getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked` or iterate the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you called the item() function with no parameter although you have to pass the index as parameter of the item() function, i.e. for example:

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).checked;
```

is used to get the checked attribute of the first item returned by the getElementsByTagName() function

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
```

or

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes[0]
   .getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).checked;
```

Assuming you want the first `input`